# Autofill credentials of a login webpage with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Anyone knows why I can not autofill the input credentials of a webpage with this code? Is there any way to make this work?

```js
function Test() {
  var name = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  document.forms["formulario"].submit(); //form submission
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" target="_top" action="https://www.allianz.pt/area-privada">
  <input id="usuario" name="_58_login" type="text" value="examplelogin" runat="server" />
  <input id="password" name="_58_password" type="password" value="examplepassword" runat="server" />
  <button onclick="Test()" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  More so because your logic is trying to get `name` and `password`, and never using those variables.

Comment: The question is how can I autofill the credentials of webpage: https://www.allianz.pt/area-privada  when I run javascript code. How can I use this variables to fill credentials of webpage? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You got the values from the inputs.  So why would you need to "autofill" inputs with the values they already have?

Comment: The inputs haven't the values. They are empty.

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById("usuario").value;` <= That line is finding the element with that id and then **getting** the value out of it, to store in a local variable.  If that input does not have a value, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok, How can I correct this?

Comment: As the answer below shows.  you `document.getElementById(<theId>).value = 'newValue';`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't inputting anything into the values you are just grabbing the form inputs. You have to declare what you want as the value.

```
function Test() {
  var name = document.getElementById("usuario");
  var password = document.getElementById("password");

  // declaring your name and password in the values
  name.value = "your name";
  password.value = "your password";

  document.forms["formulario"].submit(); //form submission
}
```

Comment: I run the code with your suggestion but it is not work as well. Do you understant why this is not working?

Comment: Did you place in your username and password here  // declaring your name and password in the values
  name.value = "your name";
  password.value = "your password";

Comment: Now I tried do this but it is not working yet. document.getElementById("usuario").value = "examplelogin";
document.getElementById("password").value = "examplepassword";